# What does "Message Catalog Not Found" mean?

Tags: java, websphere, message-queue

I have a MDB running in WebSphere, when it tries to pull a message off an MQ Queue
the following exception is thrown:

com.ibm.mq.MQException: Message catalog not found

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add the directory containing the **mqji.properties** file to the CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

Google says it's a missed entry in the classpath:
http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=5979&highlight=mqji

Answer (score 0):

The mqji.properties files is already included in the mq jar file.

The Message Catalog not found exception is thrown as part of a "MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this error was thrown because I had the Queue Connection Factory defined
at server level (on the WebSphere v6 server) and the wrong classloader was being used to 
load the above mentioned properties file.

I solved the issue by redefining factory at cell level.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message you'll be getting *with* the message catalog is pretty useless, too, here is a little patch for the mq.jar:

1. Get jad
2. Disassemble MQException and MQInternalException (the latter is only necessary because it inherits from MQException; we won't change it).
3. Add this code to MQException:

   ```
       // PATCH New fields
       private final static IntHashMap completionCodes = new IntHashMap ();
       private final static IntHashMap reasonCodes = new IntHashMap ();
       static
       {
           addCodes (completionCodes, "MQCC_");
           addCodes (reasonCodes, "MQRC_");
       }

       /**
        * PATCH Create a map of names for the MQ error codes
        * 
        * @param map
        * @param prefix
        */
       private static void addCodes(IntHashMap map, String prefix)
       {
           Field[] field = MQException.class.getFields();

           try
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
               {
                   String name = field[i].getName();
                   if (name.startsWith(prefix)) 
                   {
                       name = name.substring(prefix.length());
                       int value = field[i].getInt(null);
                       map.put (value, name);
                   }
               }
           }
           catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException (e);
           }
           catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException (e);
           }
       }
   ```
4. Replace `getMessage()` with this code:

   ```
       // PATCH Complete rewrite
       public String getMessage()
       {
           if(ostrMessage == null) {
               String rc = (String)reasonCodes.get(reasonCode);
               if (rc == null)
                   rc = "ReasonCode "+reasonCode;
               String cc = (String)completionCodes.get(completionCode);
               if (cc == null)
                   cc = "CompletionCode "+completionCode;

               String message = "MQJE001: "+cc+" "+rc;

               if(msgId == 0)
                   ostrMessage = message;
               else {
                   String s = msgId+" {0} {1}";
                   if (exceptionMessages != null) {
                       s = exceptionMessages.getString(Integer.toString(msgId));
                   }
                   if(numInserts > 0) {
                       Object as1[] = new String[numInserts];
                       if(numInserts > 0) as1[0] = insert1;
                       if(numInserts > 1) as1[1] = insert2;
                       s = MessageFormat.format(s, as1);
                   }

                   ostrMessage = message+"\n"+s;
               }

               if (underlyingException != null)
                   ostrMessage = ostrMessage + "\n" + underlyingException.getMessage();
           }

           return ostrMessage;
       }
   ```
5. Either compile these two classes into a new jar or patch the original mq.jar.

Instead of the MQJE001: RC 2 CC 2035, you'll get "MQJE001: FAILED NOT_AUTHORIZED"